# Setting up a QGIS Plugin Development Environment in Visual Studio and PTVS

Tags: qgis, python, visual-studio

I would like to create a plugin using Visual Studio 2015 and Python tools (PTVS). I have a basic hello world plugin written outside visual Studio and It loads fine in QGIS 2.10 Pisa. I have installed the Visual Studio and PTVS and I am looking for a way to work using the Visual Studio Environment.

I have set up a Python environment within visual studio however I cannot get the REPL prompt to work. Has anyone done anything similar?

Comment: REPL prompt does not work in my VS 2015 QGIS 2.12 Lyon.  It appears I have set up python environment correctly in PTVS mostly using autocomplete.  The intellisense refresh database is always incomplete.  The interactive window freezes. Simple code encounters error module _ctypes not found.  I simply want to do code an application and not a plugin, so the answer does not apply, and it does not appear correct to me in any case

Answer (score 3):

You can debug plugin in Visual Studio 2015.

1. Create project file for VS2015 and add break points in code.
2. Start QGIS dont load plugin.
3. Go to `Debug -> Attach To Process` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>  + <kbd>P</kbd>). Find the qgis process and attach to it.
4. Break point is hit and you can debug

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you also know how to setup intellisense?

Comment: for my code it works by defualt. I did not know how to setup the intellisense for QGIS API. Lets add this to your question.

Comment: also if you think answer is correct please mark it.

Comment: @NikhilMurarka can you please share your Visual Studio Python environment configuration? How do you set up Visual Studio to connect to the correct version of Python that QGIS is using? What is the Prefix Path, Interprepter Path etc? Thanks

Comment: @NikhilMurarka Hi Nikhil, will you share how to add python environment for VS and how the process of qgis added.