# Autocompletion for VS and Eclipse when debugging QGIS plugins

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, visual-studio, eclipse, debugging

I have been trying to get autocompletion to work in first Eclipse and afterwards tried with Visual Studio. I have been following these guidelines / Stack Questions

[IDE settings for writing and debugging plugins](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/ide_debugging.html)

[import qgis.core problem with QgsFeature and QgsGeometry ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152691/import-qgis-core-problem-with-qgsfeature-and-qgsgeometry-importerror-dll-load-f)

[Setting up a QGIS Plugin Development Environment in Visual Studio and PTVS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/166921/setting-up-a-qgis-plugin-development-environment-in-visual-studio-and-ptvs)

In both environments I managed to be able to debug the python code step by step, but iI was not able to get any code completion.

I suspect that its the same issue in both cases. I have been trying to add all possible paths to the `PYTHONPATH`. Both in Eclipse and in windows environment variables.

[image]

According to the guideline I did open Eclipse using a bat script to init windows specific things for QGIS.

```
call "C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\bin\o4w_env.bat"
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\QGIS 
2.18\apps\qgis\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
C:\software\eclipse\java-oxygen\eclipse\eclipse.exe
```

I made a similar script for VS without success.

The configuration I have been setting up for the python env. looks like the following.

[image]

What could I be missing that causes Eclipse not to recognize libs such as `qgis.core`?

Could it be the same reason that causes VS to not recognize it?